# A smartphone that can run Whatsapp and has never had, and never will have, iOS or Android installed?

Tags: smartphones

What smartphone do people recommend that can run Whatsapp on an OS that is not iOS or Android and has never had either of those OSes installed, or any other software produced by Apple or Google?

Using a web browser on the phone and then using Whatsapp through the web would be fine, but unfortunately it's not fine because WA requires an initial WA login through the app. For this reason (alone), I need a phone that can have the WA app installed.

Comment: WhatsApp is [only supported on](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1150261202542208) iOS, Android, and [KaiOS](https://www.kaiostech.com/). Your options are going to be extremely limited to phones that come with KaiOS preinstalled. It looks like KaiOS even comes with "software produced by Apple or Google" by default so that requirement is making it impossible to recommend anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look at some phones that have KaiOS preinstalled. It doesn't seem that KaiOS can be installed on the Librem 5. But WA is supposed to be able to run (possibly with low functionality) on the Android emulator Anbox.

Comment: You can hack some phones and put LineageOS on it although it does use the Open Source part of Android (partially devved by Google)

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a solution using **WhatsApp Web To Go**, downloadable from **F-droid**, on top of the **Lineage OS**.

AIUI (corrections welcome) this is a gateway to WhatsApp Web rather than a WhatsApp program running on the mobile device, but it sounds fine for your needs.